# How to get unique entries in a file in shell script

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, grep

I have a file:

```
a
a
a
b
b
a
c
a
c
b
```

I want out put

```
a
b
c
```

Can we do it using grep or awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach:

```
sort -u INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 3):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk '!u[$0]++' file
a
b
c
```

Nice thing with this solution is the file doesn't need sorting first.